# How to display multiple HTML annotation schemes in multiple lines in Potato annotation tool

Tags: python, html, user-interface, layout

This question is related to the open-source Potato annotation tool ([Github code](https://github.com/davidjurgens/potato) and [user guide](https://potato-annotation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)).
I am doing something similar to the [text summarization evaluation task](https://github.com/davidjurgens/potato/blob/master/project-hub/summarization_evaluation/configs/summ-eval.yaml), but I need to use a longer list of `"annotation_schemes"` in the config .yaml file than the manual example.
Using the yaml file linked above, the UI is displayed like this

[image]

However, when I add more than about 10 annotation schema, the UI becomes very cluttered an not user friendly at all (see below).

[image]

My question is: is there an easy way to add some sort of line break so that I can choose to display no more than say 4 evaluation boxes per line and have other boxes showing on separate lines so the UI is much nicer to visualize? Can this be done simply by adapting the yaml config file or would this require extensive editing of the underlying codebase of the project?